# Update table content while dragging the element using jquery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

my question is can we update the table content while dragging/resizing the div.The content is the position and size of the div that is dragged or re-sized 
please help mee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using jQuery Draggable, you could use the [`drag`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-drag) part of it:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    drag: function() {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
         $(this).html(offset.left + ', ' + offset.top);
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QH6QP/